# Не работают потоки

Tags: python, многопоточность, сокет

Создаю простой чат с использованием модулей socket (для соединения) и threading (для паралельного отправления-получения)

При попытке использовать вместо обычних функций потоки вилетает ошибка после подсоединения (на стороне сервера):

```
Connected:  ('127.0.0.1', 50133)
Exception in thread get_thread:
ENTER: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Davyd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Davyd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\restico_project\Python\chat_app\server.py", line 14, in get
    data = con.recv(1024)
OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом
```

Вот код сервера:

```
import socket
import threading as th

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 2020))
s.listen(1)

con, addr = s.accept()

print('Connected: ', addr)

def get():
    while True:
        data = con.recv(1024)
        if data:
            print('RECEIVED: ', data.decode('utf-8'))

def send():
    while True:
        data = input('ENTER: ')
        if data:
            con.sendall(data.encode('utf-8'))

send_thread = th.Thread(target=send, name='send_thread')
get_thread = th.Thread(target=get, name='get_thread')

send_thread.start()
get_thread.start()

con.close()
```

Код клиента:

```
import socket
import threading as th

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 2020))

def get():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if data:
            print('RECEIVED: ', data.decode('utf-8'))

def send():
    while True:
        data = input('ENTER: ')
        if data:
            s.sendall(data.encode('utf-8'))

send_thread = th.Thread(target=send, name='send_thread')
get_thread = th.Thread(target=get, name='get_thread')

send_thread.start()
get_thread.start()

s.close()
```

Не могу понять текст исключения, поскольку ошибка точно в не сокетах, когда убираю потоки и просто запускаю функции всё нормально.

Тогда в чем дело?

PS:
При попытке добавления ожидания закрития процеса появляется то же самое исключения:

```
File "D:\restico_project\Python\chat_app\server.py", line 14, in get
    data = con.recv(1024)
OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом
```

PS 2:

удалил s.close() и con.close(), теперь всё в принципе работает. (но хотелось бы закривать всё-таки)

PS 3:

вернул код к изначальному состаянию + правки @eri, всё также работает

Comment: close не должен запуститься пока не пройдет join

Comment: @eri, извиняюсь, вернул код к изначальним состоянию + ваш совет, тоже работает

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
send_thread.start()
get_thread.start()

s.close()
```

Вы закрыли сокет сразу после старта тредов. Дождитесь завершения тредов перед закрытием сокетов

```
send_thread.start()
get_thread.start()
send_thread.join()
get_thread.join()   
s.close()
```

*П.С. переходите на asyncio.Protocol - это перспективней и без тредов.*